# Single sign-on (SSO) without SAML/OAuth/OIDC

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, project, login-script, autologin

Guess we are all tired of login and password system and want to go passwordless.
I saw that the only solution to login without hassle is via SAML, well bad news you have to pay some SaaS apps like slack, miro, agile crm... to have access to SAML configurations.
I'm trying to build a website, like a portal where I have links to thoses website and I just click on them and I'm auto sign-in (SSO Dashboard).
I don't want to be dependent of in-browser remember password or any password keeper like bitwarden. I want to store all of my user pass in my database.
Any hints to do this ? 
I already tried this solution : https://crunchify.com/automatic-html-login-using-post-method-autologin-a-website-on-double-click/ it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Convenient. Then someone just needs to get their hands on your database to get all of your passwords in clear text.

Comment: If we assume that my db is not secure, yes. But as it is a single point of failure it is "easy" to secure what I need to secure. It's the same thing with any password keeper, bitwarden store everything. in one DB so they added authentications, and encryption to secure datas... same goes with in-browser password managers...
In the end I'm trying to make a chomium extension to auto-fill and submit on forms but it's so tricky. I hope that some day SSO will be a feature for core security and not luxury feature
https://sso.tax/

Comment: So you don't want to store your passwords in a secure password system's database, but you want to store them in your own database which you will then secure? From all that you've described, you're not so much interested in the security that SSO provides, but in its convenience, which, yes, is a luxury feature.

Comment: Exactly ! I prefere to secure it myself than store it elsewhere. While talking with others who is interested in "SSO" without SAML, they end up using on-premise BitWarden which is in the end a form filler.